# php string comparison, why cast to float

Tags: php, string

Ive come across this code

```
<?php

$a = md5('240610708');
$b = md5('QNKCDZO');

echo "$a\n";
echo "$b\n";
echo "\n";
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($a == $b);
```

This evaluates that 2 strings which could be a number `0exxxxxx`. I understand that if either are used in a numeric context then the string will be taken as a number, as confirmed by http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E'
>   and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by
>   PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other
>   cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

Im just not sure why `==` triggers a numeric comparison when both sides are of type string.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky im aware of `===` but what's causing both sides to be treated as float when both sides are string. I Know it happens when there are multiple types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

This is the result of "smart" comparison for strings in PHP. Yes, it is not what you can expect, but for now - it is how it's implemented.

## Digging deeper

**Maintaining comparison**

To realize reason for this, you'll need to look into PHP sources (for greater good or bad). In PHP, there is such thing as [`compare_function`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_operators.c#1457) which is used to handle comparisons. It contains different cases for different types of arguments. So, for strings it is:

```
case TYPE_PAIR(IS_STRING, IS_STRING):
    zendi_smart_strcmp(result, op1, op2);
    return SUCCESS;
```

`TYPE_PAIR`, as any other stuff, is just a macro.

**Moving deeper**

From previous step, we're now moving to [`zendi_smart_strcmp`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_operators.c#zendi_smart_strcmp). It is PHP's "smart thing" to compare two strings. And here we are:

```
if ((ret1=is_numeric_string_ex(Z_STRVAL_P(s1), Z_STRLEN_P(s1), &lval1, &dval1, 0, &oflow1)) && (ret2=is_numeric_string_ex(Z_STRVAL_P(s2), Z_STRLEN_P(s2), &lval2, &dval2, 0, &oflow2))) 
{
    //compare as two numbers, I've omitted this
}
else 
{
    string_cmp: //yes, yes, we're using goto
    Z_LVAL_P(result) = zend_binary_zval_strcmp(s1, s2);
    ZVAL_LONG(result, ZEND_NORMALIZE_BOOL(Z_LVAL_P(result)));
}
```

Inside omitted code there is also part for determining if result is `long` or `double` - but that's irrelevant since we've already know what caused comparison as floats: as long as strings can be treated as numbers, PHP will use that to produce comparison - and - yes, **that is intended** (so, yes, string `"1000"` is *equal* to `"1e3"` when using `==` operator, same for `"255"` and `"0xFF"` - they don't contain "e" (exponent) part, but still are *equal*)

## Solution

You may restrict the case with, for example:

```
var_dump("0e8" == "0e6"); //true
```

So no need to deal with md5 hashes. If compare that as numbers, it's true (since both operands are valid floats, and `0 x 10^8` == `0 x 10^6`). But they are not same as strings. Thus, your direct solution would be - use `===` operator to compare:

```
var_dump("0e8" === "0e6"); //false
```

Yes, it's a confusing thing in PHP - because it is not obvious (and debatable at least). But that's how it currently works.